# USB devices disappear after Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: usb, sound, 16.10

I've been having this strange issue with my computer ever since I upgraded to 16.10.  I have two USB devices connected to my computer (my Logitech wireless adapter for my mouse and keyboard, and my USB headset).  Every so often they'll just stop working.  Sometimes if I re-connect the mouse adapter to a different port it'll start working again, however this isn't the case with the headset.  Once it disappears from my list of devices, it won't come back until after I restart my computer.  Not too sure what's going on, I have *Windows on the same computer and the two devices work without any issue on there*.

Not sure if it's related, but the quality of my actual sound card on my computer has sounded pretty bad since the 16.10 update too.

I was able to trigger that simply by loading up a youtube video, it disconnected immediately as it started playing.  My mouse and keyboard stayed connected, but the sound on the headset is totally out and it's not  listed under the "output devices". [`dmesg` output](//paste.ubuntu.com/23449912/) – money quote:

```
[  186.351700] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: HcDoneHead not written back; disabled
[  186.351715] ohci-pci 0000:00:12.0: HC died; cleaning up
[  186.351776] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
```

- [`lspci -nnk | grep -A2 USB`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23451894/)

Comment: The next time one of the devices (or both) stop working, could you please leave them plugged in, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1), run `sudo dmesg | tail -n 100` and [capture the output](/q/420981/175814)? (You can unplug and plug them back in now.) Then upload the content of that file to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and [edit] your question to include a link to the pastie. Thanks.

Comment: Can you install the latest sound drivers for your computer? That might help the quality

Comment: Is there any chance that this is a hardware issue, i. e. the USB connection is mechanically or electrically unstable? Can you try to plug your devices into a different USB port? What's the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 USB`?

Comment: Installing sound drivers is unlikely to reconnect a device that's fallen off the bus.. ;-)

Comment: It doesn't seem like it, I've had both of the devices plugged into different USB ports for a few days now.  I've even tried having them on USB 3.0 ports as well.  Running them in windows, or when I had 16.04 I never had any sort of issue like this.  https://paste.ubuntu.com/23451894/

Comment: It won't be very helpful, but since I can't put it in the comment I'm adding here - the problem might be related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/848337/ubuntu-16-10-usb-devices-disapper-after-running-multimedia-files. I'm experiencing the same, seems to be a kernel bug in one of USB related modules.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve a similar problem (in my case with a usb sound card which would disconnect after working for a few seconds, bricking the port to which it was connected) by installing a more up-to-date kernel:

4.9.0-040900rc3-generic

I simply downloaded the .deb file for my architecture from, http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and installed it with the software updater.

After rebooting, the usb device was back to its normal behavior.