# Ubuntu 16.10 USB devices disapper after running multimedia files

Tags: usb, kernel, 16.10

I got this problem after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10
As soon as I run ANY video files (in browser or just from hdd), all usb-devices instantly switches off until reboot (PC don't freezes 'cause when I push power-off button, menu appears. 
`/var/log/kernel.log` shows thousands of these lines:

```
kernel: [  681.844553] AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=00:12.0 domain=0x0006 address=0x0000000000000080 flags=0x0020]
```

I can't show `dmesg` output 'cause I can't do anything until reboot.

On same PC I have openSUSE and Windows 8.1, working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve a similar problem (in my case with a usb sound card which would disconnect after working for a few seconds, bricking the port to which it was connected) by installing a more up-to-date kernel:

4.9.0-040900rc3-generic

I simply downloaded the .deb file for my architecture from, http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and installed it with the software updater.

After rebooting, the usb device was back to its normal behavior.